# including libcurl in CMake Env

Tags: c++, c

I use a Cmake build env, which generates Make files. I wanted to include libcurl library as I am getting a link error with curl APIs.  Where to include libcurl library for static linking.

---

Build error Log:

```
Linking C executable lwm2mclient
CMakeFiles/lwm2mclient.dir/core/objects.c.o: In function 'lwm2m_imp_actuate1':
objects.c:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to 'curl_global_init'
objects.c:(.text+0x9a): undefined reference to 'curl_easy_init'
objects.c:(.text+0xbd): undefined reference to 'curl_easy_setopt'
objects.c:(.text+0xd5): undefined reference to 'curl_easy_setopt'
objects.c:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to 'curl_easy_perform'
objects.c:(.text+0xef): undefined reference to 'curl_easy_strerror'
objects.c:(.text+0x111): undefined reference to 'curl_easy_cleanup'
objects.c:(.text+0x116): undefined reference to 'curl_global_cleanup'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make[2]: *** [lwm2mclient] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/lwm2mclient.dir/all] Error 2
```

Comment: Maybe you should show your cmake file.  You need to add `-lcurl` or equivalent to the library list for the `lwm2mclient` program, but I'm not sure of the details.

Answer (score 1):

In your cmake file(CMakelists.txt), you have to add a link_directories, for example:

> ```
> link_directories(your_libfile_directory)
> add_executable(executable_name  file_c_cpp)
> target_link_libraries(executable_name curl)
> ```

For more details: http://www.cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/